# Update Form validator on boolean change

Tags: flutter, validation, dart, setstate

I created a flutter login / register screen and want to give an error if the firebase returns an error:

```
if (formState.validate()) {
  formState.save();
  try {
    UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    User user = userCredential.user;
    Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, HomeScreen.routeName);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
    print("failded with error code ${e.code}");
    //catch if user not found
    if (e.code == "user-not-found") {
      setState(() {
        //set true to update validator
        wrongEmailOrPassword = true;
        print("Error caught");
      });
    }
    //catch if password wrong
    if (e.code == "wrong-password") {
      setState(() {
        //set true to update validator
        wrongEmailOrPassword = true;
        print("Error caught");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

by setting the boolean to true u want to update the input validator so that it returns an error:

```
validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return (kPassNullError);
    }
    if (wrongEmailOrPassword) {
      return (kWrongEmailOrPassword);
    }
    return null;
  },
```

But it doesnt work and doesnt update the validator / error messages. It just updates it if I reload the form. How can I update the error messages after I pressed the submit button?

Thanks for reading the long text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validator functions are only called when you `validate()` the form. So one simple solution would be to just call `formState.validate()` again after receiving and setting the error. You probably don't even need the `setState` there then.